# React calculator: limiting number of inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m trying to make a React calculator. It´s mostly done, but I have one problem I don´t know how to correct: I can´t seem to limit the number of operators an user can enter (for instance, I want to limit "++++" to just "+" and also prevent two operators getting joined: +- must become -). I tried resetting the state everytime an user enters an operator, but no dice. I´m seriously lost here. I thought about a Regex, but it seems to be rather problematic (way too many contexts to try).

```
class Calculator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(evt) {
    const id = evt.target.id;
    const result = evt.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: `${prevState.value}${result}`.replace(/^0+\B/, '')
    }));

    if (id === 'equals') {
      this.setState({ value: math.eval(this.state.value) });
    } else if (id === 'clear') {
      this.setState({ value: 0 });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to solve this. The main problem with using the `includes()` based approach is that it does not enforce a correct format in the input string. Perhaps you could use a regular expression like this?

```
/^\d*([/\+-/*=]\d+)*$/gi
```

This would prevent problems like multiple operands like `+++`, and so on:

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {


 super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(evt) {

    const result = evt.target.value;

    // Update state
    this.setState({
      value: result
    });

    // Comine previous state with input value
    //const combination = `${ this.state.value }${result}`;
    console.log(result, 'combination', result)
        // Use regular expression to check valid input. If invalid
    // prevent further processing
    if(!result.match(/^\d*([/\+-/*=]\d+)*$/gi)) {
      console.error('Invalid input')
      return
    }

        this.setState({ calculated: eval(result) });

  }

  render() {
  return <h1>
  <input value={this.state.value} onChange={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}/>
  <p>{ this.state.calculated }</p>
  </h1>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

There is a functioning [JSFiddle here for you to try out](https://jsfiddle.net/3m7sk8jd/)

Comment: Thank you. But React says it´s an invalid RegEx. I need it to not only stop duplication of characters, but also prevent different operators from showing up (for instance, "+-" must become "-")

Comment: Nope, it removed all of the click events. Think the regex is detecting EVERYTHING as an invalid input, since that´s what the console is logging.

Comment: Update: it does seem to work. But it´s also blocking the "="  and the "clear" buttons and doesn´t let you change your mind (for instance, "+" becomes a permanent "+" until you enter another number)

Comment: Hahaha, sorry, I don´t want to sound ungrateful but it doesn´t: now you can´t add more than one number everytime (eg, you can´t put 36, just 3 or 6).

Comment: Nope, it doesn´t. Plus it console.logs combination and doesn´t use it.

Comment: Yeah. I think React is not taking the regex properly. Think I need to add template literals for it. How do I add an exception for "clear"?

Comment: when pressing the button with the id "clear" to reset state back to 0...I don´t want to return invalid input

Comment: Sorry, I keep getting "unnecesary escape character" when I use it. this.setState(prevState => ({
  value: `${prevState.value}${result}`.replace(`${/^\d*([/\+-/*=]\d+)*$/gi}`)
}));

Answer (score 0):

You could save a list with operations and the crrently typed character. Then before inserting check if it's an operation to prevent adding multiple of them

**example**

```
const ops = ['/', '+', '-', '^']
this.setState({lastChar: result})

// Before setState with the full formula
if(this.state.lastChar === result && ops.includes(result)) else if (ops.includes(this.state.lastChat) && ops.includes(result)) return;
```

*assuming `result` is only the typed/clicked character*

**problems**

This strategy is definitely not perfect. For example, typing 1+-2 or 1*-3 wouldn't work. But from here on you could tweak it to fit your needs

*I'm on my phone, sorry for the bad formatting*

Comment: It works. But I still need to make it not allow different operators (for instance, not + and - at the same time). Any ideas on that? thanks!

Comment: I uodated my answer before reading the comment but I actually mentioned your request as an imperfection because it limits the capabilities of the calculator